# React / Redux: mapStateToProps not actually mapping state to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using React and Redux on a project, and I'm having problems implementing a feature to enable/disable a button. I've been able to:

- trigger a method
- have that method trigger an action creator
- dispatch an action
- catch that action in the reducer and create a new, updated state
- see the updated state in Redux DevTools

However, the enable/disable functionality still doesn't work, as it seems that `mapStateToProps` and `connect` aren't actually mapping the state to the props. I'm tracking `canSubmit`, which changes within the state but is `undefined` in the props. What am I missing to successfully map the state to the props?

Relevant code:

UserFormView.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  routerState: state.router,
  canSubmit: state.canSubmit
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch)
});

class UserFormView extends React.Component {
```

...

```
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserFormView);
```

Actions:

```
export function enableSubmit(payload) {
  return {
    type: ENABLE_SUBMIT,
    payload: payload
  };
}

export function disableSubmit(payload) {
  return {
    type: DISABLE_SUBMIT,
    payload: payload
  };
}
```

Reducer (using a createReducer helper function):

```
const initialState = {
  canSubmit: false
};

export default createReducer(initialState, {

  [ENABLE_SUBMIT]: (state) => {
    console.log('enabling');
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      canSubmit: true
    });
  },

  [DISABLE_SUBMIT]: (state) => {
    console.log('disabling');
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      canSubmit: false
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Are you wrapping your app in a <Provider> and passing in the store?

Comment: Yep. That's in a different file:
`render () {

    return (

      <Provider store={this.props.store}>

        <div>

          <ReduxRouter>

            {routes}

          </ReduxRouter>

          {this.renderDevTools()}

        </div>

      </Provider>

    );

  }`

It's all built off @davezuko 's React-Redux-Starter-Kit, so the basic wiring's pretty solid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're not creating reducer with key `canSubmit`. It depends on your store configuration, to be more specific — on how you import your default export from reduces file. Another thing to mention here, it's likely you'll have reducer with the name `canSubmit` and a key `canSubmit`, so you'll need to reference it in code like `state.canSubmit.canSubmit` — you're returning object from action handlers on reducer, not simple `true` or `false` boolean values.

Comment: I believe this is the cause.  An easy way to see what the reducer is called would be to log the state out in the `mapStateToProps` function and see what your state tree looks like: `const mapStateToProps = (state) => { console.log(state); return { routerState: state.router, canSubmit: state.canSubmit } };`

Comment: @Michael that's a good place for such logs! Another thing I'd recommend to try is redux devtools chrome plugin — it does marvels for debugging redux apps ;-)