# My mapStateToProps is not passing props to component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am really newbie in Redux development. Just started two days ago

Before, I used props - state pattern but I am going to change some parts of state -  props pattern to Redux.

First, I will show my codes. index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ItemList from './itemList';
import SearchList from './searchList';
import {Provider,connect} from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './storeReducer';
import {backToMain} from './reduxAction';
class App extends React.Component{
    // not important some codes 
    render(){
        return(
            <div> 
                <section id="Search">
                    <form  action="//localhost:80/ReactStudy/travelReduxApp/public/server/itemList.php" id="Search" className="search" method="GET" onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                        <input ref={'search'} placeholder="search country, attraction names" type="text" name="search"/>
                        <button type="submit">SEARCH</button>
                    </form>

                    <p className={this.state.validateError.display}>
                        {this.state.validateError.type=='invalid value'?
                            'Only english letters are available in this input'
                        : (this.state.validateError.type=='not found')?
                            'Nothing was found with this keyword. Try again'
                        :'Empty text field'
                        }

                    </p>
                </section>
                <ItemContainer initializeSearch={this.initializeSearch} searchList={this.state.searchItem}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class ItemContainer extends React.Component{
    state={
        viewMain:true
    }
   //some codes
    showMain=()=>{
        this.setState({
            viewMain:true
        })
        this.props.initializeSearch();
        store.dispatch(backToMain());
    }

    render(){
        console.log('Item container');
        console.log(this.props);
        return(
            <section id="ItemContainer">
                {
                    this.props.searchList!=''?
                        <SearchList searchList={this.props.searchList} mainVisible={this.state.viewMain}/>
                    :
                        <ItemList toggleView={this.toggleView} mainVisible={this.state.viewMain}/>
                }
                <button onClick={this.showMain}>Back to main</button>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps =(state)=>{
    console.log('working');  //it doesn't show it.
    return{
        visible:state.visible
    }
};
const wrappedSearchList = connect(mapStateToProps,null)(ItemContainer);
const Root = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>
);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Root/>,
    document.getElementById('App')
)
```

reduxAction.js

```
export function backToMain(){
        return{
            type:'BACK_TO_MAIN'
        }
    }
```

storeReducer.js

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {backToMain} from './reduxAction';


export const initialState = {
    visible:true
}
export const store = createStore(viewMainReducer,initialState);
export function viewMainReducer(state=initialState,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'BACK_TO_MAIN':
            console.log('Back..');
            return{
                ...state,
                visible:true
            }
            break;
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

I am really newbie in Redux so maybe I did not understand official document perfectly but I know mapStateToProps must pass state to the component as props. In my case, the component should be ItemContainer component.

Problem is when ItemContainer component is rendered.
 If I check with

```
console.log(this.props)
```

in ItemContainer's render method , in console I see only initializeSearch and searchList are passed to the component. I cannot figure out why my visible property of initialState object is not passed to the component. What could be the reason? What should I do to pass visible property to ItemContainer component?

[React / Redux: mapStateToProps not actually mapping state to props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930098/react-redux-mapstatetoprops-not-actually-mapping-state-to-props)

read this thread but I just did not understand ...

Comment: But you never actually use `wrappedSearchList `.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I also think that is the point. How should I change my code?  How should I do to use wrappedSearchList? https://gist.github.com/markerikson/121c77a01c453466361a9c6434a08620 should I do like code in here? change class to const and add props parameter?

Comment: First you want to capitalize component name `WrappedSearchList`, then you just use it instead of `ItemContainer` in `App#render`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thanks. I will try

Answer (score 0):

Try using `wrappedSearchList` instead of `ItemContainer`

```
<wrappedSearchList initializeSearch={this.initializeSearch} searchList={this.state.searchItem}/>**strong text**
```